# How to create clone of website with websockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket

How to create a full copy of site and run it's in localserver?

I'm tried to copy site with "Httrack, wget and other", run this in "python http-server" and "nodejs http-server", but all i got is "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400". And site don't displayed correctly. (Sorry for my bad grammar, i'm not native speaker)

Comment: It sounds like whatever you're trying to "clone" is trying to open a websocket to something that doesn't exist in your environment.  More to the point, you can "scrape" content from a web site (with wget, or a web crawler) ... but you generally can't "clone" a web site.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

At least, not generically.  You can't take a site that uses dynamic server-side content and interaction and make a static rip of it unless you know something about the site and can replicate it's features, or you are willing to take a fixed snapshot of the DOM.